# Who is Wolfgang, played by Atilla Pinke, in Underworld?

Tags: character-identification, actor-identification, underworld

The credits for *[Underworld](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0320691/)* list [Atilla Pinke](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1455547) as the actor who played Wolfgang. Who is this character, or who is his actor?

The names surrounding Wolfgang in the credits are mostly vampires, with some humans. The name [Atilla](http://www.behindthename.com/name/ati50lla/) is apparently a Turkish variant of the Hungarian name [Attila](http://www.behindthename.com/name/attila). Since *Underworld* was filmed in Hungary, I wonder if the actor’s name is misspelled: it’s possible that his name is Attila Pinke. He may be a Hungarian who had a non-speaking role, like [Sándor Bolla](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1456417/), who played [Rigel](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Rigel), and [Judit Kuchta](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1454961/), who played [Zsusza](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Zsuzsa).

[image: Underworld credits]

Is there a picture of the actor or the character? The Underworld Wiki speculates that the character could actually be [Duncan](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Duncan), a vampire who spoke no lines and was never named in the film. The novelization lists his name as Duncan, but perhaps he was intended to be named Wolfgang in the film. The novelization does not mention anyone named Wolfgang.

I can’t find an official script of *Underworld*, but the transcripts I’ve found make no mention of “Wolfgang” or “Duncan”.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPAsS1XU9e8?

Comment: @Valorum Hmm, he does kind of resemble Duncan. [fish guy](https://youtu.be/gPAsS1XU9e8?t=8m3s), [vampire](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/File:Duncanbetter.jpg)

Comment: The names listed are not in order of first appearance, so I can’t figure out who Wolfgang is from that.

Comment: Jázmin Dammak’s name is misspelled on the line just before Wolfgang. I suspect that the guy who Valorum found is the actor.

Comment: He is. I'm in contact with him. He's confirmed what scene he was in but i'm struggling to pinpoint him.

Comment: @Valorum I saw some twittering... good work. I'm a bit surprised he mentioned a party, since I had convinced myself that he looks like Duncan, who never attends any parties (as far as I can see). Lots of people are standing around in the background in some staircase scenes, and some non-staircase party scenes, so who knows...

Comment: What has confused me is that there is no scene that's quite like the one he's described where Selene walks down the staircase to the party below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a brief twitter conversation with [Attila Pinke](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/749678839442313216), I believe I've managed to narrow down his character by a simple process of elimination.

> **Q.** *I'm trying to work out who played who. What part did you play and did your character have a name?*
>
> **AP:** *I was in the scene in a house, **where the main actress is coming down
> the stairs at a party.** The name was Wolfgang*

[image]

For the record, there are no scenes where Selene (Kate Beckinsale) walks down the staircase in the mansion, I suspect that he's actually referring to **Erika** (Sophia Myles) who is seen on the staircase at timestamp 00:12:31.

[image]

Comment: You misspelled his name the same way that they did in the credits. Feel like sending that screenshot to Attila, or would that be pestering him, since he hasn’t responded to your last message? That does seem like quite a good match though.

Comment: @amaranth - He's a business-owner. I suspect he's reasonably busy and in the absence of any reason to prod him further, I shall leave him be. There's zero prospect that they'll change the credits for him, btw.